# sed working on one system but not on other

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

This is my input file ..

```
 [root@localhost scripts]# cat ip6hdr.txt | xargs -n4
 6000 0000 005C 3320
 2001 0000 0000 0000
 0000 0000 0000 0100
 2001 0000 0000 0000
 0000 0000 0000 0200
```

I want to change the last two digits of first line of the file i.e. `20` to `00`.

I tried this..

```
cat ip6hdr.txt | xargs -n4 | sed '1,1s/\([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\) \([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\).*/\1 \2 \3 \400 /'
```

Previously it was working fine on ubuntu now not working on fedora in a bash script

I have no reason why it works on one system and not on other one ..

```
 [root@localhost scripts]# sed --version
 GNU sed version 4.1.5
 Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
 warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
 to the extent permitted by law.
```

if possible suggest me some alternative ..

Comment: check your sed versions, i.e. `sed --version`. Also why the complicated expression, why not `sed '1s/..$/00/'` ? Good luck.

Comment: What is your question? What are the sed versions involved?

Comment: @shellter thanks and +1 for that simple one ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why complicate things?

```
$ cat File
6000 0000 005C 3320
6000 0000 005C 3320

$ sed '1s/..$/00/;' File
6000 0000 005C 3300
6000 0000 005C 3320
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[0-9a-fA-F]` instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: Btw, why are you using so complicated sed? Why not `sed -e '1 s/[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$/20/'` instead (my point is the use of `$` to stick it to end of line)?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are missing a `-e` to indicate your sed expression and that the Ubuntu sed is newer and more permissive. The much more simple expression might work a little better:

```
.... | sed -e '1s/[0-9][0-9]$/00/'
```

Comment: Even Sun3 `sed` did not require `-e`. I only use it when I am copy/pasting a solution (well almost) ;-) Good luck to all!